# Is there any way that doubleclick trackers impressions/clicks can track where the ad is being served. Which site the ad is being displayed?

Tags: double-click, double-click-advertising

Like how can we track whether the ads are being served on the site we are paying them for,not some scam site.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's now way to tell on which publisher sites your ad tags have been implemented. However, you may use the Content Verification tool within the advertiser ad server (DoubleClick Campaign Manager if you're using DoubleClick) to flag impressions served on pages that contain sensitive content (i.e. adult, violence, gambling, alcohol, etc).